# Allow Close Button on QMainWindow when QDialog is Open

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I have one issue with Qt Close Option when there is QMainWindow is open and on Push button Clicked I am opening one QDialog.Now my requirement is to allow close option is QMainWindow to call closevent of QMainWindow .

Now the senario is when I pressed Button on mainwindow,  QDialog open and Close button on upper most right is disabled in QmainWindow. So pls let me know how to enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you don't want to have your GUI blocked while dialog is open, right?

Use a **modeless** dialog:

```
void EditorWindow::find()
{
    if (!findDialog) {
        findDialog = new FindDialog(this);
        connect(findDialog, SIGNAL(findNext()), this, SLOT(findNext()));
    }

    findDialog->show();
    findDialog->raise();
    findDialog->activateWindow();
}
```

Note: The code was taken from the Qt documentation. Notice that we are not using a `QDialog::exec()` method but just `QWidget::show()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for support you are right it was a problem of modeless

I have Just added as per Example above:

```
 findDialog->setModel(false);
 findDialog->show();
```

Before Show I have added `setModel(false);` and its then working like a charm !!!

Thanks and Regards 
Praveen Kumar

Comment: it should be setModal, not model

Comment: Hi ,   Using SetModel I am able to access QMainwindow that is every event that was created was working that is not fine at all.  It is allowing each and evry button.

Comment: Now I am Disabling that setModel(false);  but again My Question is how to Close Mainwindow from taskbar when QDialog is Open